# Android Client with Asynchronous Way

Tags: android, performance, asynchronous, client

I am trying to make a client with asynchronous. I am not good in Java. Then its a bit difficult for me. I want to recieve and send data as much as performance.. And I think Asynchronous is the best option for it? I wanted to use cometd but its more complicated.. anyway What can I do for it? or Which way I should follow?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). There are various ways to do work on separate threads. See [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).